# How to connect to another web application

Tags: sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-server, web-application

I have a SP 2013 web application. In this site have a custom list.

```
(Ex: site: http://site1:1111, list name is "AAA")
```

I want to write a Common Library project c#, this project can get data from "AAA" list, and can use for another web application

```
(Ex: site: http://sharepoint1:2222).
```

Help me please. I know that need provide user, password to connect.

Answer (score 0):

You can user sharepoint client side object model to copy data from one farm to another farm.

You can create different client context for different farms.

Check [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: Can you help me tutorial or sample code ? thanks so much

Comment: Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912(v=office.15).aspx. In this article check Retrieve items from a SharePoint list Section

Comment: How about certificate user? There are 2 web applications

Comment: No certificate required for using CSOM . You have to set the credentials object of client context object